# Use Python flask or NodeJS for controlling stepper motors via Web?

Tags: gpio, python, node.js

Im planing a project where I need to controll some stepper motors with my RaspberryPI. I'd like to controll those motors interactively via a web GUI. This server should run on my Py.

Now I found a couple of similar projects and I decided to also use websockets for communication with my PI in order to be real time.

There seems so be a nice approach with NodeJS and Socket.io. GPIOs would be controlled directly with some npm libs. On the other hand there is standart Python with flask wich has similar capabilities.

I really cant decide wich aproach I shold take and what the real differences are.

Maybe someone could geive me some advice and insight?

Thanks in advance and hava a good one!

Comment: Hi @FabZbi, in general, questions in stackexchange.com should not ask for an opinion, as everyone will have their own. The aim here is to get precise answers to technical questions or problems. However, I will share my experience, and maybe it can help you make a decision. If this is your first web project I would highly suggest you use Flask. It is complete enough to get a robust project up and running. It is easy and flexible enough that it might do what you need, and it plays nice with other tools that are typical in full stack development.

Comment: Okay great! Thanks for your response! I will look deeper into Flask then :)
And I'm sorry that I used stackexchange wrong then, I'm just wondering where is the place to ask such design questions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: it's OK. I'm not sure what other forum I could recommend. Perhaps on Reddit you can get more opinion-based answers. Good luck with your project!

Comment: If you ask "*What application is better?*" then it is very likely that your question will get flagged to close because it's mostly opinion based. But if you ask "What are the differences between these applications using a Raspberry Pi?" then for my understanding the question is OK. You may take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Comment: @David I would make your first comment an answer. Then *@FabZbi* can accept it.

Comment: @Ingo, thank you for your suggestion. I just added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, questions in stackexchange.com should not ask for an opinion, as everyone will have their own. The aim here is to get precise answers to technical questions or problems. However, I will share my experience, and maybe it can help you make a decision.

If this is your first web project I would highly suggest you use [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). It is complete enough to get a robust project up and running. It is easy and flexible enough that it might do what you need, and it plays nice with other tools that are typical in full stack development.